# Installed selenium with pip, folder is in site-packages, using correct interpreter, but still cannot import (Win10, Python 3.10.9)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, pip, modulenotfounderror

I'm trying to use selenium, but can't get python to recognize it.

I installed it first using "pip install selenium" and "pip install webdriver-manager". It is in the folder *"C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages\selenium"*, but I get the error **"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'"** when I try to import it.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVplU.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wiREJ.png)

Here it is shown as installed with the command "pip list"
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhOu7.png)

I also tried uninstalling it and reinstalling with flags that I saw some people say worked, but it didn't make a difference.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTTMU.png)

I only have one python interpreter version installed, 3.10 (so only one python folder, "Python310"). I have pandas in the same site-packages folder which I can import and use no problem.

If anyone knows what the issue might be, please let me know. I can't figure it out for the life of me.

Comment: from the first screenshot it looks like Visual Studio Code has the wrong interpreter. You should click on where it says "3.10.9 64-bit (microsoft store)" on the bottom and point it to the python interpreter you *have* installed, the one in "AppData\Local"

Comment: @mlg556 When I tried to change interpreters, only the one labeled (microsoft store) was in the list. I solved the issue by uninstalling that version and reinstalling from the python website.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved the issue by completely uninstalling the interpreter which I got from the Microsoft Store and reinstalling it from the official Python website. Now "from selenium import webdriver" works.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium) installed in the global scope is not getting recognized within the *Virtual Environment* of *VS Code* / *PyCharm*.

---

### Solution

You need to install [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) within the *Virtual Environment*.

Within the *Terminal* execute the command:

```
pip install -U selenium
```